# Android - Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.widget.ImageView#setAlpha

Tags: android, eclipse

its showing me error on setAlpha

```
private void updateNextButton(){
    if(currentPosition == totalItem - 1){
        nextBtn.setAlpha(0.5f);
        nextBtn.setClickable(false);
    }
    else{
        nextBtn.setAlpha(1f);
        nextBtn.setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

and log is giving following error

--

### java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.ImageView.setAlpha

please help me some devices giving error.

Comment: [`setAlpha`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)) was only added in API 11. Check out the NineOldAndroids library as a replacement: https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/blob/master/library/src/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewHelper.java

Answer (score 0):

What this means is you defined your app to run on Android versions down to version 8. The feature you want to use requires API 11. You can set your min SDK to 11 to fix it or look for a 3rd party library that will run the feature on API 8.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html